# Reset Boost Installation

Tags: 18.04, boost

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine, which ships with a default Boost `1.65` version. 
A few months ago, I had installed Boost `1.72` version from Source. This is becoming very problematic since ROS (Robot Operating System) had been installed with the `1.65` version. This is an issue since cmake finds Boost `1.72` as the Boost version.

Is there a way to get back my `1.65` installation as default. I do not even know if that installation of boost has been deleted or not. I want to revert back to my default boost installation as it was, with cmake pointing to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did the source-built version get installed (`/usr/local/` - or someplace else?)

Comment: Yes it got installed in `/usr/local`